# on the continuity of matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $f:\mathbb R^{n\times n}\to \mathbb R$ given by  $f(A)=||A||$. where $A$ is a matrix e $||-||$ is a matrix norm.  On the domain, consider any other matrix norm $||-||'$.

> Prove that $f$ is a continuous map, namely that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $abs(||A||-||B||)<\epsilon$ whenever $||A-B||'<\delta$.

This is my proof for the case when $||-||=||-||'$. From the inverse of the triangle inequality we have $abs(||A||-||B||)\le ||A-B||$, so if we choose $\delta=\epsilon$ we get the thesis.

For the general case probably one should use the equivalence between matrix norms but I can't see how.

I would like to know if my partial proof is correct and how to prove the general case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

For any other norm, since $\|A-B\|\le C\|A-B\|'$ for some $C>0$ (because any two norms are equivalent), you get
$$
\bigl|\|A\|-\|B\|\bigr|\le \|A-B\|\le C\|A-B\|'<C\delta.
$$
So you can take $\delta=\epsilon/C$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct, so far.

Any two norms on a *finite*-dimensional vector space are comparable. (Use compactness of the unit sphere and continuity of norm.) Thus you'll have $c>0$ so that $\|X\|\le c\|X\|'$, and this should do it.